# Uncheck a group of checked input type="checkbox" with a single button

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, input

I have a `#main-container` with groups of input type checkboxes. These checkboxes open up button lists when checked.

The `#main-container` that holds all of this can be closed by a button. The problem I have is how do I make this button that closes `#main-container` also uncheck any checkboxes that are left checked when the #main-container is closed?

At the bottom I have included the only way I know to do it with Javascript at the moment, but that means making a variable for each checkbox and that checkbox must have a unique ID. I am trying to avoid that.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>input checkbox</title>
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background: beige;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    .main-container {
      border: 1px solid red;
      width: 25%;
      position: relative;
    }
    .toggle-box {
      display: none;
    }
    label {
      margin: 0.2em;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      transition: all 1s linear;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
    .toggle-box + div {
      display: none;
      margin: 0.2em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .toggle-box:checked + div {
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid black;
      transition: all 1s linear;
    }
    button {
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="main-container" class="main-container">
    <label for="toggle-box">A</label>
    <input class="toggle-box" id="toggle-box" type="checkbox" >
    <div>
      <button type="button">submit</button>
      <button type="button">submit</button>
    </div>
    <label for="toggle-box2">B</label>
    <input class="toggle-box" id="toggle-box2" type="checkbox" >
    <div>
      <button type="button">submit</button>
      <button type="button">submit</button> 
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="test1"></div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="closeMe()">close</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="openMe()">open</button>
  <script>
    function closeMe() {
      var $toggleBox = document.getElementById("toggle-box");
      $toggleBox.checked = false;
      document.getElementById("main-container").style.display = "none";
    }
    function openMe() {
      document.getElementById("main-container").style.display = "block";
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function closeMe() {
    var $toggleBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle-box");
    $toggleBoxes.forEach(function(box){
        box.checked = false;
    });

    document.getElementById("main-container").style.display = "none";
}
```

`document.querySelectorAll` return an array of all the matched element (match with a css selector). Then, we loop through all those elements using `forEach` (you can use a `for` loop instead if you want).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` to select all checkboxes for example:

`var cbks = document.querySelectorAll('.toggle-box');
cbks.forEach(function(val){ 
   val.checked = true; 
});`

Comment: if you want to add code, select it then press the `{}` button. Use '`' just for inline code.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the checkboxes by getElementsByClassName and then iterate over all the check box and set the checked value to false.

```
var $toggleBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-box");
[].forEach.call($toggleBoxes, function(elem) {
      elem.checked = false;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>input checkbox</title>

  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      background: beige;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    .main-container {
      border: 1px solid red;
      width: 25%;
      position: relative;
    }
    .toggle-box {
      display: none;
    }
    label {
      margin: 0.2em;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      transition: all 1s linear;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
    .toggle-box + div {
      display: none;
      margin: 0.2em;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .toggle-box:checked + div {
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid black;
      transition: all 1s linear;
    }
    button {
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main-container" class="main-container">
    <label for="toggle-box">A</label>
    <input class="toggle-box" id="toggle-box" type="checkbox">
    <div>
      <button type="button">submit</button>
      <button type="button">submit</button>
    </div>
    <label for="toggle-box2">B</label>
    <input class="toggle-box" id="toggle-box2" type="checkbox">
    <div>
      <button type="button">submit</button>
      <button type="button">submit</button>
    </div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div class="test1"></div>


  </div>

  <button type="button" onclick="closeMe()">close</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="openMe()">open</button>




  <script>
    function closeMe() {
      var $toggleBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("toggle-box");
      [].forEach.call($toggleBoxes, function(elem) {
      elem.checked = false;
      });
      document.getElementById("main-container").style.display = "none";
    }

    function openMe() {
      document.getElementById("main-container").style.display = "block";

    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @chatterb0x Glad to help :)